# Adding bullets back to a list after setting list-style:none; globally

Tags: css

How do I add bullets back to a list when I've applied `list-style:none;` globally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class to the list, like `with-bullets`, and set the `list-style` for that class to `circle`.

E.g.

**CSS**

```
.with-bullets {list-style:circle}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="with-bullets">
    <li>Value 1</li>
    <li>Value 2</li>
</ul>
```

There's also lots of other stuff you can do with `list-style`: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style.asp

Answer (score 0):

you can use `pseudo` css for styling the list styles which will not effect the `li` styles and you can give any style for the `li` like i have done

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/sbmam1vj/5/

add a class for `ul` for which you want to change the styles

currently i have used `star` for list style you can use anything

```css
ul.line-legend {
  list-style: none;
}
.line-legend li {
  position: relative;
}
.line-legend li:before {
  content: "\2605";
  color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: -19px
}
```

```html
<ul class="line-legend">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to override css, here are 2 of them:

Option 1: inline css

```
<ul style="list-style:circle">
    <li>Value 1</li>
    <li>Value 2</li>
</ul>
```

Option 2: using !important

**html**:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li>Value 1</li>
    <li>Value 2</li>
</ul>
```

**css**:

```
.list{
    list-style:circle !important;
}
```